# How to mock methods which take or return a Span<T>

Tags: c#, .net, mocking

We have been using moq which relies heavily on expression trees and reflection.emit. But Span is not allowed to be in an expression tree, so methods which take or return a Span cannot be mocked with it.

We have been working around this by manually creating the Mocks by implementing the interfaces ourselves. But it's time consuming and far from ideal.

How can I mock a method that takes or returns a Span?

Comment: Use `Memory<T>` instead of `Span<T>`.

Comment: @aepot Although that is a valid workaround, my code doesn't need Memory<T> and it seems wrong to force Memory<T> usage on my design just because of mocking.

Comment: Did you check if this is possible with the new Stunt mechanism in the upcoming Moq 5?

Comment: @KlausGütter I had a look but that is not released and development has stalled only one commit this year and nothing since Feb 5th, Also the docs are almost non existent, so trying to figure out if it will help is almost impossible. I'm looking for something I can use now.

Comment: Not nice, but you could create an adapter class implementing the interface in question and delegating the method with the `Span<T>` parameter or return value to a new virtual method which has e.g, `T[]` instead. Then create a `Mock<Adapter>` and mock the new virtual method.

Comment: I wouldn't be put off by recent commits. The moq gitter feed is active, if you get no joy here post up there. They have been very helpful for a couple of my queries that aren't covered on SO

Comment: I added a Github issue to NSubstitute regarding this: https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/665

Comment: It's the end of the Q1 2022 and this still seems to be an issue. Moq5 isn't out yet and we are still unable to mock `Span<T>`. Has anyone been able to find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb here as I've only focused on making it testable, perhaps missing some other considerations. One option I see is to indroduce a wrapper `SpanProvider<T>` which would deffer the construction of `Span<T>` until you run your use case.

```
public class SpanTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void SpanReturningDependencyTest()
    {
        var spanDependency = new Moq.Mock<IDependencyReturningSpan>();
        spanDependency.Setup(d => d.SpanUseCase()).Returns(new SpanProvider<int>(
            // test case data
            [2, 3, 4]
            ));

        var spanConsumer = new SpanConsumer(spanDependency.Object);

        Span<int> result = spanConsumer.GetResultUsingSpan();

        result[0].Should().Be(2);
        result[1].Should().Be(3);
        result[2].Should().Be(4);
    }

    public interface ISpanProvider<T> where T : struct
    {
        public Span<T> ToSpan();

    }

    public class SpanProvider<T> : ISpanProvider<T> where T : struct
    {
        private readonly T[] values;

        public SpanProvider(T[] values) => this.values = values;

        public Span<T> ToSpan() => new Span<T>(values);
    }

    public interface IDependencyReturningSpan
    {
        SpanProvider<int> SpanUseCase();
    }

    // "Real" implementation
    public class SpanGetter : IDependencyReturningSpan
    {
        public SpanProvider<int> SpanUseCase() => new SpanProvider<int>(
            // use case data
            new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
            );
    }

    public class SpanConsumer
    {
        private readonly IDependencyReturningSpan spanGetter;

        public SpanConsumer(IDependencyReturningSpan spanGetter) => this.spanGetter = spanGetter;

        public Span<int> GetResultUsingSpan()
        {
            Span<int> useCaseSpan = spanGetter.SpanUseCase().ToSpan();

            return useCaseSpan;
        }
    }
}
```